# PHP functions seems to have an issue

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo, return

something in this code doesnt work correctly. So need your help.

I have written a function in an external file:

```
function userExists($conn, $user){
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($results) > 0):
        return true;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

And i call this function here:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,email,password,active FROM user WHERE email = :email');
    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(userExists($conn, $email) === false){
         echo 'False';
    }else{
         echo 'True';
    }
endif;
```

But the output is everytime true.. maybe I can't see the wood for the trees.

Thx

Comment: `$results` is an object. It's `count` is always gt 0. Use `[]` notation to get count value.

Comment: So should i use something like count(results['email']) > 0 ?

Comment: `print_r($results)` please and see what you can use.

Comment: Sidenote: you are doing a select on the user table twice with the same where clause, which makes the second call (from userExists) kind of redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Results will be greater than 0 at all times because your query is returning the value 0. So results does contain a value. Rather do this

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM user WHERE email = :email";"
if($result['Total'] > 0)
{.....}
```

Comment: It's `Total` key, not `total`